# How to force RTL for the default android menu programmatically despite what locale is set?

Tags: android

I have a menu like this:

[image: menu]

I always want the main app's layout direction to be LTR. However, I want this menu to be RTL when I set the locale to a RTL locale in the settings. Is there anyway to set the layout direction programmatically? Setting it through the XML files will just have it be overwritten by the MainActivity's onCreate code.